# How to read into a pandas dataframe the wollowing json?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following json:

```
[
    [
        {
            "A": "2017-02-02T11:57:41+0000",
            "B": "agent",
            "C": "hi how are you son."
        },
        {
            "A": "2017-02-01T22:19:58+0000",
            "B": "user2",
            "C": "M contestan"
        },
        {
            "A": "2017-02-01T22:19:42+0000",
            "B": "user2",
            "C": "preetty thanks you?"
        },
        {
            "A": "2017-02-01T22:19:28+0000",
            "B": "user2",
            "C": "the cat sat over the fox"
        }
    ]
]
```

How can I compose it into a pandas dataframe like this?:

```
A B C
2017-02-02T11:57:41+0000 agent Hola Alex, si no has realizado la modificación de los datos afiliados, por favor confírmanos tu DNI, celular y operador para revisarlo. Gracias.
....
2017-02-01T16:22:30+0000 user1 Hola me han depositado un dinero a mi nombre, no tengo cuenta en este banco, puedo saber por aquí si ya puedo cobrar? DNI 42782263 gracias
```

I tried to build it with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.apply(lambda x: map(x.from_records, json_path))
```

And

```
df = pd.DataFrame('../path/file.json')
```

And with `read_json()`, However it is not working. Thus, How can I build the dataframe from the json?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [17]: import json
```

Assuming you have the following JSON string:

```
In [18]: s
Out[18]: '[[{"A": "2017-02-02T11:57:41+0000", "B": "agent", "C": "Hola Alex, si no has realizado la modificacin de los datos afiliados, por
favor confrmanos tu DNI, celular y operador para revisarlo. Gracias."}, {"A": "2017-02-01T22:19:58+0000", "B": "user2", "C": "Me podran ayud
ar?, estoy llamando al CC y no contestan"}, {"A": "2017-02-01T22:19:42+0000", "B": "user2", "C": "No me llega el sms con la clave token"}, {
"A": "2017-02-01T22:19:28+0000", "B": "user2", "C": "Tengo problemas para hacer pagos de servicios desde la app"}, {"A": "2017-02-01T22:19:1
8+0000", "B": "user2", "C": "Buenas tardes"}], [{"A": "2017-02-01T22:19:12+0000", "B": "agent", "C": "Hola Alexander, as es, el dinero ya se
 encuentra disponible puedes acercarte a cualquiera de nuestras tiendas el nmero es 1703070024597. Buenas noches"}, {"A": "2017-02-01T16:22:
30+0000", "B": "user1", "C": "Hola me han depositado un dinero a mi nombre, no tengo cuenta en este banco, puedo saber por aqu si ya puedo c
obrar? DNI 42782263 gracias"}]]'
```

you can parse it:

```
In [19]: data = json.loads(s)
```

and build a DataFrame:

```
In [31]: pd.DataFrame.from_records(np.concatenate(data))
Out[31]:
                          A      B                                        C
0  2017-02-02T11:57:41+0000  agent  Hola Alex, si no has realizado la mo...
1  2017-02-01T22:19:58+0000  user2  Me podran ayudar?, estoy llamando al...
2  2017-02-01T22:19:42+0000  user2    No me llega el sms con la clave token
3  2017-02-01T22:19:28+0000  user2  Tengo problemas para hacer pagos de ...
4  2017-02-01T22:19:18+0000  user2                            Buenas tardes
5  2017-02-01T22:19:12+0000  agent  Hola Alexander, as es, el dinero ya ...
6  2017-02-01T16:22:30+0000  user1  Hola me han depositado un dinero a m...
```

Comment: Thanks, Max... However the list is actually a nested list (i.e. I have several lists of dicts), for this reason I am just getting one list into the  `df` .I tried to do: `df = pd.DataFrame(*d[0])` and `pd.DataFrame(d[0][:])`... In my previous attempt I tried to map or use a lambda... how can I fix this issue?.

Comment: Thanks for the help Max!